# The /sdcard direcory and other directory conventions: how is the Android filesystem structured?

Tags: external-sd, file-system, internal-sd

I am using the "adb shell" command to access either of an LG P690 (device A) or a Samsung Galaxy SIII (device B). Device A also has a 32GB microSD card plugged in while device B does not. When fromthe shell prompt I `cd /sdcard` and do a `df` I get:

- On device A: `/sdcard` Size 14G Blksize 8192
- On device B: `/sdcard` Size 12G Blksize 4096

Does this refer to internal memory? Device B also has a `/storage` directory which holds 0 bytes (what is this?).

Also, both have a `/data` directory which I know is where installed apps go. Is this also on internal storage? How do I know whether `/data` is on internal or external SD?

I'm confused as to why a directory called `/sdcard` would refer to internal as opposed to external memory. Is there no FHS standard for the Android file system as there is for Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's two different things, at least the first depending on a) Android version, b) manufacturer, and c) sometimes even the device in question:

- before Android 4.0, `/sdcard` usually was were the *external SDCard* was to be found
- starting with Android 4.0 (or even 3.x?), this changed for most devices, and usually became the place of the so-called *internal SDCard*
- where the *external* SDCard is found with the latter group, differs a lot. Locations known to me include:

  - `/sdcard_ext`
  - `/sdcard/external_sd`

What really resides where, you can check with commands like `mount` or `df`. While `mount` will list all mounted file systems (including the "virtual" ones like e.g. `/proc` and `/sys`), together with details on where they were mounted from and what options have been used, this might be a bit confusing (at least to beginners). So you might rather want to use `df`, which sticks to the "real file-systems": it does not show where they are mounted from, but instead shows their total/used/free space, which might be even more useful to figure out what matches best.

As for `/data`: Yes, this usually resides on internal storage -- but might also depend on implementation. With Android 4.x, "internal storage" and "internal SDCard" are often "unified" (i.e. the "internal SDCard" often is nothing but a directory on internal storage). This was done a.o. to get rid of the problem of a filled-up internal storage (it can "expand" into the internal SD area now), or a full internal SDCard and plenty of space on internal storage (can "expand" the other way around, too -- as it's all the same "drive").

Comment: Still, on device B df command shows /data and /storage/sdcard0 as different partitions even though both have the same capacity and show same amount of used space. On this device /storage/sdcard0 and /storage/extSdCard are probably the internal and external SD cards.

Comment: Looks correct to me. As for internal storage/internal SDCard: as I wrote, that very much depends on implementation. It's encouraged to use "unified storage" (see [this blog](http://www.blogsolute.com/memory-management-usb-storage-ice-cream-sandwich/21956/) and [this session transcript](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/11/18/impromptu-qa-session-with-android-engineer-dan-morrill-brings-to-light-reasons-behind-galaxy-nexus-lack-of-usb-mass-storage/)), but it's not enforced in any way.