# Filesytem on Android

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, file-system

I'm totally confused regarding Android file system and its relation to SD card.

While browsing my Asus Nexus 7 (2013) with file manager `Astro` from very root catalog I found directory `sdcard`. But there is also catalog `/mnt/sdcard` that points to the same location. Why do I need both of them?

I got mixed twice while browsing my rooted `Samsung S4` Lollipop with external SD card. `ES file Explorer`. It has :

```
/sdcard/ with some information that is not on SD card. But why this directory is called SD scard?
```

Mount directory:

```
/mnt/
  /extSdCard/ with card information inside that can be visible on PC if I 
remove it from phone and put to computer.
  /sdcard/ again pseudo SD card info.
```

Totally confused:

```
/storage/
  /emulated/0/ that contains /sdcard/ info
  /legacy/ the same like /emulated/0/
  /extSdCard/ linked to real SD card
  /sdcard0/ again pseudo SD card info.
```

What is idea of such strange file system organisation?

Answer (score 1):

There are already answers for all parts of your question, so let me sum up:

- [Android Folder Hierarchy](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46926/16575) has some general information
- [Confused by the many locations of the virtual /sdcard/](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/39542/16575) should answer the last part of your question
- [The /sdcard direcory and other directory conventions: how is the Android filesystem structured?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/44721/16575) might also be helpful

If you take a closer look at `/sdcard` from a terminal (or via `adb shell`) using the `ls` command, you will see it is a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) (the Wikipedia article explains it in detail), usually created for at least two reasons:

- make it easier for you to find it
- have a "canonical place" for it, regardless of where it is physically

There's of course more to it, but that would become too lengthy for an answer here :)